# Is converting uint16_t into uint8_t[2] using a cast valid in C?

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a function that converts `uint16_t` into `uint8_t[2]` in C.

The following code has been tested, but even after reading the disassembly, I'm not sure it's portable or safe.

```
static inline uint8_t* write_u16(uint16_t in, uint8_t out[2], ArchEndian_t endian) {
    if (NATIVE_ENDIAN != endian){
        in = byte_swap(in);
    } 

    *((uint16_t*)out) = in; //< Is this portable and safe?

    return out; 
}
```

How should I think about typecasting in C?

Comment: Recall that `NATIVE_ENDIAN` here needs to refer to the endian of integers, specifically 2-byte integers.  Rarely today the endian of 4-byte integers have more than 2 choices and endian of FP values may differ from integers.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, Historically, yes. But I've been wondering if that's still the case. Does anything newer than the PDP-11 use something other than LE or BE?

Comment: The PDP endian is fairly ancient.  Endian of FP not matching integer endian may still occur these days although I have not experienced one in over 10 years.  The key is that your goal of _portable_ depends on how well code determines `endian` too, something not shown.  IAC, C2X will likely introduce `__STDC_ENDIAN_LITTLE__, __STDC_ENDIAN_BIG__, __STDC_ENDIAN_NATIVE__` and any code written today should consider how well it works with those.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No compiler/libc seems to have implemented stdbit.h yet though, for some reason.

Comment: @Lundin Interesting. Planning for the future C2X is tricky.  I had expected it out in 2023, now 2024.  Maybe 2025?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ISO/IEC is such a dinosaur organization. They've had the finished draft for 1.5 years now and haven't achieved jack. With their wheels of bureaucracy grinding this slow, then ISO/IEC simply _can't_ be used for technical standards any longer. During this time, mankind has designed & released _thousands_ of advanced microcontrollers with C in mind, but ISO cannot even manage to publish a pdf in that time... We can't have a dinosaur organization clogging up technical progress this bad, they need to be replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a cast for this violates the strict aliasing requirement.

You should instead use `memcpy` this way:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static inline uint8_t *write_u16(uint16_t in, uint8_t out[2], ArchEndian_t endian) {
    if (NATIVE_ENDIAN != endian) {
        in = byte_swap(in);
    } 
    return memcpy(out, &in, sizeof(in));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have a reference suggestion so I can better understand what you imply by strict aliasing violation?

Comment: @gberth, It implies you could get alignment issues, as my answer mentioned. Some environments can only address 16-bit values if their address is divisible by two.

Comment: @ikegami Strict alasing violation and alignment issue are *not* the same thing. Strict aliasing violation typically causes compiler to emit completely invalid instruction sequence, where as alignment issue typically causes issue when reading or writing memory location at runtime.

Comment: @user694733 You have the cause and effect reversed. Strict aliasing doesn't exist because compiler will generate junk. The compiler is allowed to generate junk because of strict aliasing. Strict aliasing exists because of alignment.

Comment: @ikegami No. Strict aliasing violation can happen even if type used to access object has the same alignment requirements as the object being accessed.

Comment: @user694733, Of course. And that doesn't contradict anything I said. Implications are not reversible. So not "no". At best, you've demonstrated that there could be a second reason for strict aliasing to exist, which is entirely possible.

Comment: @ikegami alignment requirements have nothing to do with aliasing rules, strict aliasing exists (as the name implies) to allow compilers to assume that certain values (i.e. values with different types) do not alias each other. This is important because it allows compilers to avoid generating redundant load/stores, without strict aliasing they'd have to prove that any accessed value is not aliased by any other accessed value to be able to do that.

Comment: @ikegami The [Strict aliasing exists because of alignment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78225863/is-converting-uint16-t-into-uint8-t2-using-a-cast-valid-in-c?noredirect=1#comment137910218_78225900) is amiss.  Yet look like we all agree using `(uint16_t*)out` is a problem.

Comment: Re "*strict aliasing exists (as the name implies) to allow compilers to assume that certain values (i.e. values with different types) do not alias each other*", Yes, we both know what strict aliasing means. The question at hand is why it exists. /// Re "*without strict aliasing they'd have to prove that any accessed value is not aliased by any other accessed value*", They have to do that even with strict aliasing. Because we *can* have aliases. (`q = (char*)p;`,  pointer parameters without `restrict`).

Comment: @ikegami: If alignment were the reason for the aliasing rules, the rules would be “An object shall have its stored value access only by an lvalue expression whose alignment requirement is at least as strict as the alignment of the object.” They are not. The primary reason for the aliasing rules is so a compiler can better optimize inside `void foo(float *x, int *y) { … }` by assuming `x` and `y` point to different memory. The fact some aliasing, as with character types, is allowed limits the utility of this, but this remains the purpose for the rules.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*If alignment were the reason for the aliasing rules*", I merely said it's *a* reason. I already acknowledged there could be others. (Straw man argument) [Made this more clear in my answer]

Comment: @ikegami: Alignment is not a reason for the aliasing rules because it is covered by other rules, notably C 2018 6.3.2.3 7. Aliasing rules would have a byproduct of preventing (in the sense of making undefined) some misalignment issues but not all **if there were no other rules about this**, but they do not solve all alignment issues and that is not their purpose or reason for existence. There are other rules about alignment, and they suffice for that without the aliasing rules. Aliasing rules do not solve the alignment problem. They solve the problem of enabling more compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

No. It could violate alignment issues and it violates the strict aliasing requirements.

Use `memcpy`, shifts or a union. A decent compiler will optimize that to a simple move instruction if possible.

```c
memcpy( out, &in, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You can fact-check me on this, but I think union conversion is UB. I didn't go for `>>` for speed reasons.

Comment: Re "*I didn't go for >> for speed reasons.*", Again, a decent compiler will optimize that to a simple move instruction if possible. There should not be any speed penalty.

Comment: @gberth "but I think union conversion is UB." --. In C, it is OK, yet need to see specific code to verify.